# Display nested List using ngFor -Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a list with different categories and created another list with articles, in articles list i am maintaining categoryId which is id in categories list.

Now I wanted to display categories and need to display articles based on the category.

Here my code is:

List of categories and articles

```
Articles:Article[] =[{id:1,name:'Article1',categoryId:1,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article1 '},{id:2,name:'Article2',categoryId:1,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article2 '},{id:3,name:'Article3',categoryId:2,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article3 '},{id:4,name:'Article4',categoryId:2,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article4 '},{id:5,name:'Article5',categoryId:3,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article5 '},{id:1,name:'Article6',categoryId:3,publichedOn:new Date,description:'Article6 '}]


Categories:Category[] =[{id:1,name:'Category1'},{id:2,name:'Category2'},{id:3,name:'Category3'},]
```

Displaying list of categories and articles

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
    {{category.name}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let article of getArticlesForCategory(category.id)">
        {{article.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

getArticlesForCategory function will return the articlesList based on the category id.

Tried to display articles based on the returned list but i am unable to call function from ngFor

am i missed any thing? or Is There any other way to do the same?

Comment: Can you please define `not working anymore`? What's the behavior now?

Comment: I am unable to call a function in ngFor

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwgjpz I've copied exactly your code and stackblitz runs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend transforming your data structure into something more useful - maybe behind a service:

```
groups: any = 
     this.Categories.map(t=> { 
        return { 
            id: t.id, 
            name: t.name, 
            articles: this.Articles.filter(x=>x.categoryId == t.id) 
        } 
     });
```

Then in your template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let group of groups">
    {{group.name}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let article of group.articles">
        {{article.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick replay but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: import { map } from 'rxjs';

Comment: imported using import{map} from 'rxjs/operators/map'; but showing same error

Comment: probably just missing 'this'